# Create and animate view in constraint layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I want to create a view (i.e. TextView) in my constraint layout and animate it's position on button click.

This is how my onClick looks like:

```
   fun onClick(view: View) {
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        val txt2 = TextView(this)
        txt2.text = "Hello2"
        txt2.textSize = 70F
        txt2.id = View.generateViewId()
        tid = txt2.id
        layout.addView(txt2)
        val cs = ConstraintSet()
        cs.clone(layout)
        cs.connect(txt2.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, textbox.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
        cs.connect(txt2.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, layout.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        cs.connect(txt2.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, layout.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
        cs.applyTo(layout)

        startAnimation(txt2.id)
    }

    fun startAnimation(txt: Int) {
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout)
        val cs2 = ConstraintSet()
        cs2.clone(layout)
        cs2.connect(txt, ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 50)
        cs2.applyTo(layout)
    }
```

Animation works if I create TextView somewhere before actual click, but how to do this in one shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem in the way how android calculate layout. When you call TextView(this) and layout.addView(txt2) view created and added to children list, but have no height, width and position on screen. In Looper of UI thread will be enqueued task to layout textView, that call onMeausure and layout for txt2 and its children. If it enqueued in UI thread, it will be copmlite after your functions finish, and you start animation before tx2 was "layouted".

I see 2 ways to resolve this. First: create txt2 in layout on start of activity or specify it in xml, just not create constrains for it and set visibility to GONE. ConstraintSet.applyTo correctly works with appearing and disappearing when it change visibility. Second: put starting of animation as delayed. Not the perfect solution, but it should works.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
  startAnimation(txt2.id)
}, 100)
```